# How to run sonar scanner on an Ionic 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have migrated our frontend project from `ionic/es6/angular` to `ionic2/typescript/angular2`. Everything is good except we don't know how to run sonar report on the project.

Previously we are using gulp and run `gulp sonar` command to generate the sonar report (on an local sonar server).

We don't use gulp in the new ionic2 project and wonder how to run the sonar scanner on the new project.

**Note**

1. we have installed typescript plugin on our sonar server.
2. we have added `sonar-project.properties` file in the project rood directory

Question is how to run it

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried the [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam thanks for your information. I've installed sonar-scanner and now it can run through the sonar report. However I found the report is perfect with no bug, no vulnerabilities, no code smells absolutely perfect, even I creates a bug deliberately, it still turns out nothing. I checked my sonar setting, and I am sure the rules are activated, the project is linked to a quality profile (typescript). Any idea?

Comment: 1) What extension do your files use? 2) What does your analysis log tell you about how your project is being processed?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam 1) `.ts`, 2) yes it come up with the number of LoC

Comment: @GelinLuo: Please do share the contents of sonar-project.properties.file.

Comment: @GelinLuo Did you get anything works? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sonar-scanner tool from [sonar](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Installing+a+Scanner) and run it in the project folder:

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=your-project \
  -Dsonar.organization=your-org \
  -Dsonar.sources=. \
  -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io \
  -Dsonar.login=8ed524debb4f53489e99bd66eb5110a3e8c2958e
```

Personally, I used my repositories pipelines to do the scan.

Answer (score -5):

the answer you are finding is has been already solved

in that link i am giving you

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

check it out

Comment: The link you shared is an obvious thing and most Sonar user (including me) has already read it. There is nearly no value in the answer you put. Please do NOT post obvious thing just to get the bounty points.